# Browser Based Guidebook - Not Public Facing (Users Want to Email Tool to Each Other)

Tags: javascript, excel

Users want a web-based rendering of Excel data, but do not want it to be public-facing. Rather, they want the ability to "wrap" up this environment and email to a specialized group of staff. I have not yet received all the specs, but technology stack will include Javascript, Excel, HTML, CSS. Very small scale, so I'm not sure of the best approach. For a larger scale project I worked on, I put everything in a VM and onto a USB, for a user group and that worked fine. This group is adamant about the ability to email.

I haven't tried anything yet.

Don't have it yet.

Expected...read-only data rendered in browser/device agnostic environment. Not public facing. Emailed to specialized staff.

Comment: What have you tried in excel? any code ?

Comment: you can do a File->Save-As in Excel and turn it into a HTML document. Would just be static though, no macros etc. If it's supposed to be "read-only" then what's the need for JavaScript?

Comment: Or you could use Office365...can still be password protected, and it's web based, and it'll be fully functional. Then they can email the link to the document around, instead of the document itself. Depending on what the spreadsheet contains, maybe even the free version of Excel 365 you get with a free Microsoft account might be sufficient, or even the Google Docs clone. Don't re-invent the wheel if you can possibly avoid it. And if you can, try to wean them off the obsolete obsession with emailing (and thus massively duplicating) copies of documents all over the place!

Comment: It's an online guidebook with multiple .html pages based on the Subject. Depending on the subject, selected by the user, a reference page is rendered. Right now, they used a multiple-tabbed Excel spreadsheet for use as a "guidebook". The javascript is to retrieve the necessary page based on choice. As for Excel, I am not comfortable working with it - hate it actually. Saving the spreadsheet as html gives me a flat perspective.

Comment: Ok. I can see some inherent contradictions in the requirements here. If something is "online" then it means "accessible from the web via a URL", not "self-contained and attached to an email". You need to decide which thing you are trying to do. I would say the web-based version will be easier to use and maintain. If they still want to email things to each other, they can email the link to the URL. If people desperately require offline access to it then maybe you will need to reconsider that, of course, but unless that's an explicit requirement then these days I would assume it's not needed...

Comment: ...and if they're talking about email stuff round I'm guessing they have internet access a majority of the time anyhow. Now, I'm struggling to see what the added value in your proposed solution is going to be? The user gets a screen, then they select which subject they want from a list, and you give them a HTML version of what was in one of the worksheets in the spreadsheet? Is that the sum total of it? Or have I missed something Is that really adding a great amount more value than if you just upload the spreadsheet into Office Online and they find the relevant worksheet themselves?

Comment: Or maybe we just forget about Excel, you export the content of each worksheet into HTML, throw the Excel file away, and make a little single-page application with some hidden tabs, one for each "page", and when the user selects their subject, the relevant tab is displayed to them. That content could easily be held in a single self-contained HTML file which could live on a little webserver, or on a fileshare, or indeed be emailed around to different people as required. Or is the issue that the spreadsheet gets updated sometimes and you have to take new data from it? Again it's unclear.

Comment: And lastly I don't know what you meant by you got a "flat perspective" when you exported the spreadsheet to HTML. You mean you only got one worksheet returned? You can change the export settings to solve that. Or you mean something about the appearance? It wasn't clear what you meant or what the relevance was.

Comment: If you want some more definitive advice, you could perhaps address the points I've made here and clear up the uncertainties about the precise scenario, the intended usage, the value proposition, and the ongoing maintenance situation for updating the data (if any). I'm happy to help but it's a slightly unconventional proposal which needs clarifying a bit. Thanks.